# Retrieve data from associated database in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an **Entries** table with users_id as a foreign key to the **Users** table.

I have set the belongsTo association in the EntriesTable like so:

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

After that I wrote this in the EntriesController:

```
$entries = TableRegistry::get('Entries');
$query = $entries->findByTitle($title)
    ->contain(['Users']);
$entry = $query->first();
$this->set('entry', $entry);
```

In the VIEW template of the Entries I have to show the **username** field of the user that wrote the Entry.

I am aware that in previous versions of CakePHP 1, I could just write **$entry['User']['username']** to retrieve the username of the User who wrote the Entry. Now that I am using CakePHP 3.6, it doesn't seem to work. How do I perform the same task in CakePHP 3?

Comment: check in your controller debug($entry); Then see what is the data showing.

Comment: Would you add your view method too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like below

In controller

```
public function view($title)
{
    $entry = $this->Entries->findByTitle($title)->contain(['Users']);
    $entry = $entry->first();
    $this->set('entry', $entry);
}
```

OR

```
public function view($title)
{
    $query = $this->Entries->find('all', [
        'where' => ['Entries.title' => $title],
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ]);
    $entry = $query->first();

    $this->set('entry', $entry);
}
```

In view

```
<?= $entry->user->username ?>
```

Comment: thanks! The problem is that the parameter of my view method is not $id, but $title. it seems like get() doesn't work with fields that are not primary key.

Comment: Thanks I figured how to fix this problem by adding bits to your code:
$entries = TableRegistry::get('Entries');
        $query = $entries->findByTitle($title);
        $q = $query->first();
        $id = $q->id;

        $entry = $this->Entries->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Users']
        ]);

$this->set('entry', $entry);

Comment: @Karim Ahh, that is much better than my messy code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So in cakephp you were loading Model of its controller, which is done as default,you can directly create an find() method in same controller,if you want to find from other table/ model you can do is-

a. $this->Entries->otherTableName()->find()->all();

b. $tableName= $this->loadModel('tableName');
   $tableName->find();